# Sendemail and others authentication fail: I’m getting invalid credentials provided

Tags: gmail, smtp

Im trying to use `sendemail` and `sawks` to send an email via SMTP of mail.com or yahoo.com or gmail (those are the ones I spent almost a day).

They all are failing at authentication phase i.e. AUTH LOGIN.
I’m getting invalid credentials provided.

Ports tried:

- 464 and 587
- With and without TLS
- With and without tls after STARTTLS.

Before I was sending emails directly communicating (telnet) with gmail without any clients.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What configuration(s) are you using, what arguments for the apps?

Comment: @music2myear
swaks --to xxx@xx.com-s smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587 -tls -au xx@yahoo.com -ap xxxx
I can even telnet to 587 port and still receive same error
535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.
same story with sendemail

Comment: Please edit the question to provide additional information.  Have you looked at yahoo's help itself for directions?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved with Google!

They simply ban usage of alternate email clients which are not "secure enough" for them. Configured gmail settings to allow alternative client to pass authorization, gmail generated new pass only for that client to be used. Method that I was using 3 years ago now simply wont work.